# Verify whether the ring is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{C}^2 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

This question was part of my homework: Is it true that the ring $ \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y-x^2-x,y+x^2+x) $ isomorphic to $ \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} $?

I feel that it's true because you get two solutions, $ (0,0) $ and $ (-1, 0) $, hence we have a map defined by $ \overline{f}(x,y) \mapsto (f(0,0),f(-1,0)) \in \mathbb{C}^2 $ which is an isomorphism. Is this correct?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{C}[X]/(X^2)$. The ideal is cancelled over only one point, namely $0$, but the ring is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. Can you explain more clearly why the map you mentioned is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
(y-x^2-x,y+x^2+x)=(y-x^2-x,y)=(x^2+x,y)
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y-x^2-x,y+x^2+x)
\cong
\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+x)
\cong
\mathbb{C}[x]/(x)
\times
\mathbb{C}[x]/(x+1)
$$
which coincides with your geometric argument.